# How to do a template class (where the template extends Number) which use number addition?

Tags: java, templates, generics, numbers

Hello I want to do a really simple thing. Just make a template function for any numbers. I actually want as little as ability to "add". In C++ it would be really trivial like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline T add (T a, T  b) { 
    return a + b; 
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   printf("int: %d\n",add(1,2));
   printf("float: %f\n",add(1.1,2.1));
}
```

In Java I got a tough lesson. I'm new to Java so I believe (and hope) I'm totally wrong and over engineering this. But only thing I come up with was:

```
public interface IntrfcWowNumbersAdds<T> {
    T add(Number v);
}

public class SuperSmartInteger extends Number implements IntrfcWowNumbersAdds<SuperSmartInteger>{
    private Integer i;
    public SuperSmartInteger(int v) {
        i = v;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ""+i;
    }

    @Override
    public SuperSmartInteger add(Number v) {
        return new SuperSmartInteger(this.intValue()+v.intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return i; // thx god for auto(un)boxing
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

And note that this crazy wrapper above I would have to do for any number I would like to use template for (eg double, byte etc...)

```
public class ThreadSafeNum<T extends Number & IntrfcWowNumbersAdds<T>> {
    private T    num;

    public ThreadSafeNum(T n){
        num = n;
    }

    public T add(T v){
        // note in here I plan to do some locking...
        return num = num.add(v);
    }
}
```

then I can use it as:

```
SuperSmartInteger i = new SuperSmartInteger(5);
SuperSmartInteger i2 = i.add(6);
System.out.println(""+i2);
ThreadSafeNum<SuperSmartInteger> tsn = new ThreadSafeNum<SuperSmartInteger>(i);
SuperSmartInteger i3 = tsn.add(i2);
```

I know that when `add()` would be only adding I can just use + operator and rely on auto(un)boxing. But my `add()` method is meant to do something extra (like lock).

So how to do it properly? Or is my way correct???

Comment: You could use [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of writing your own `ThreadSafeNum` class?

Comment: Actually yes this is the best answer, although on question I did not ask. I will use that - thx! Still I wanted to know the answer for my original question just out of curiosity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this as the base class:

```
public abstract class Addable<T extends Number,U extends Addable<T,U>> {
  private final T value;
  public Addable( final T value ){ this.value = value; }
  public T getValue(){ return value; }
  public abstract U add( U addend );
}
```

And this as the sub-class:

```
public class AddableInteger extends Addable<Integer,AddableInteger> {
  public AddableInteger( final Integer value ){
    super( value );
  }

  @Override
  public AddableInteger add( final AddableInteger addend ){
    java.util.Objects.requireNonNull( addend );
    return new AddableInteger( this.getValue() + addend.getValue() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx. It is still far more uglier than C++. But at least I can delegate some coding into abstract predecessor. So your solution is bit more nice than mine. Should have find it by myself...

Comment: BTW in my example I extend Number so my `SuperSmartInteger` can be used where `Number` only is expected. You can do it also by adding to `Addable` `extends Number` at the end. And then override all `*Value()`, but only in one abstract class, not in every derived number class which is the improvement...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reasons that works in C++ is that the compiler will create as many functions as there are calls in the code, and compile each one independently in order to validate if '+' is a reasonable thing to do in that particular case. This is a little like a case of compiler-assisted duck-typing. In other words, there is no guarantee that type T will have a + operator and only the fact that the compiler will look at the actual call types and create permutations helps you.

Note that there is some risk in letting the compiler "add whatever", since there is no interface or contract that guarantees the semantics to be correct. That is what a class hierarchy brings you.

This is trickier to do in full type safety since inheritance can be complex and the return types need to be somewhat clear. Inheritance is the usual thing so that a virtual method knows how to add its own type, but in this case you can't change the class hierarchy of Number.

You can, nevertheless, do something like this:

```
public static int addAsInt(Number a, Number b)
{
    a.intValue() + b.intValue();
}
```

And the same for other return types. That will take any two instances of number and generate an output value, assuming which kind of output type you want. Somewhat easier than creating wrapper classes in this particular case.

Comment: Well thanks for response, I gave a like for try. But your solution returns always only int. Which is clearly wrong and something else than C++ would have done. In my example I ask for `T overload+(T a, T b)`. In your example is return type always `int` not `T`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. As I mentioned, you need to do "the same for other return types.". There are also in `Number` methods floatValue, doubleValue, etc etc. I provided this because the exact thing you are asking for probably does not exist (unless you starts using ugly reflection overhead or, as you mentioned yourself, a lot of overhead and custom classes, etc.), and and may not even be a good idea (I tried to explain why). Even if you have to do 5 of this methods and call them knowing which result type you want, I still feel it has less overhead and complexity than the alternative above. ;-)